# php sessions - is it possible to trigger a server script executed by a DIFFERENT user than www-data?

Tags: apache, php

i am running a php+mysql site on a lamp ubuntu cloud server (amazon ec2).  i use php sessions.

for every session (SID), i need to create a temporary folder which is a subdirectory of www and has the session Id as its name (unpredictable, therefore cannot be pre-created).  for example: /var/www/fileStore/s35S10nT3Mp/.

i will later access files in these folders from a javascript (client side) function.

i am working under the assumptions that:

1. anything executed (or called) by the php code will run under the user www-data (apache php user)
2. client-side javascript cannot access a subdirectory OUTSIDE www (for example: /var/outsideFileStore/s35S10nT3Mp/, where webroot = public_html = /var/www)

i have a security issue with giving user www-data write permissions in a subdirectory of www, because that leaves the server and data in these folders too exposed.

i would like to know if a php session can trigger (or call) a server script / process that runs under another user (who would receive write permission in /var/www/fileStore/), not www-data.  this process would then create (and garbage collect) these temporary folders.

corollary: in case this cannot be done under apache, would tomcat help (if i ran php under java as opposed to http_server)?

Comment: su_php? of course, if you're worried about giving write permissions, nothings says this other script can't be subverted as well. If you don't want the content of these sub-folders to be abused, don't put them into your document root - create a simple webservice to manipulate those folders/files.

Comment: @marcb yes, i agree, but the problem is that, since i use this code for an openlayers web application, i am obliged to call layers from javascript, which, as client-side code, cannot (i assume) access a folder outside /var/www/.  and therein, lies the rub.

Comment: yes, but nothing says that whatever your JS calls on can't act as intermediary. e.g. javascript -> get_me_the_file.php -> file somewhere outside webroot. then you can layer on tons of security on the get_me_the_file.php layer, and still leave apache able to write whatever it wants in the directory.

Comment: @MarcB pls post that as answer and i will accept it as the correct one, because that is basically how i got it to work in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compile an executable with the identity bit, owned by this alternate user. The PHP script would exec this program, which in turn could simply run the actual PHP script of your choice.

The program could be written in Perl as well -- it's the only scripting language that Linux systems permit to have the identity bit.

Comment: i will look up the "identity bit" in perl and see if that works for me.  tks in advance.